# How can I use Javascript to detect the width of an area and apply correct menu spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I use Javascript to detect the size of `menuArea` and then apply each `<li>` the right size to fit the total `menuArea`?

```js
// something like this...

var menuSpace = Math.floor((menuAreaWidth - menuButtonsTotalWidth) / (menuButtons.length - 1));
// set positions
var menuButtonsLeft = 0;

$('#menuArea .menuButtonHolder').each(function(i, buttonHolder) {
  if (i < (menuButtons.length - 1)) {
    $(buttonHolder).css({
      'left': menuButtonsLeft + 'px',
      'width': menuButtons[i].buttonWidth + 'px'
    });
  }
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
#menuArea {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li .menuButtonHolder {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuArea">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.aspx">News and Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="social.aspx">Social</a></li>    
    <li><a href="blog.aspx">Our Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Without it, in order for the menu to fill the entire `menuArea` I find myself having to trial and error different `padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px` etc until they all stretch here or there the entire distance across.

Comment: why not to do width: 16.66%?

Comment: Why don't you use `justified navigation`?

Comment: In some cases each menu item may have more text, I may not want them to have the same width you see :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript for stuff you can have your CSS do please.

Flexbox has a great way of solving this for you, add these lines to your example:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And this if you wish for your elements to respect the same width as the largest element:

```
li {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Example snippet:

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

#menuArea {
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

li .menuButtonHolder {
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
 flex: 1;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuArea">
<ul>
 <li><a href="/">Home with a really long name.</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.aspx">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="news.aspx">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="social.aspx">Social</a></li>    
 <li><a href="blog.aspx">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
<ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I was after. Thank you Sir.